# How create gaps in smoother for "missing" values (R, ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

If I have a data set like this

```
set.seed(100)
data <- data.frame("x" = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5),
                   "y" = rnorm(13),
                   "factor" = c("a","b","c","a","b", "c", "c", "a",
                                "b", "c", "a", "b","c"))
```

so it looks like this

```
   x           y factor
1  1 -0.50219235      a
2  1  0.13153117      b
3  1 -0.07891709      c
4  2  0.88678481      a
5  2  0.11697127      b
6  2  0.31863009      c
7  3 -0.58179068      c
8  4  0.71453271      a
9  4 -0.82525943      b
10 4 -0.35986213      c
11 5  0.08988614      a
12 5  0.09627446      b
13 5 -0.20163395      c
```

I would like to plot this with a separate smoother each factor (a,b,c)

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y, col = factor)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(group = factor))
```

However since there are no values for "a" and "b" for x = 3, so I would like the smoothers for "a" and "b" to have a break for x = 3. What's the best strategy to accomplish that?

Comment: what do you mean by "to have a break" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create an expansion of the combinations of `x` and `factor` and then do a database-like join on the combinations and the data. For example, first I form a new data frame `df` with the combinations of the unique values of `x` and `factor`

```
df <- expand.grid(sapply(data[, c("x", "factor")], unique))

> df
   x factor
1  1      a
2  2      a
3  3      a
4  4      a
5  5      a
6  1      b
7  2      b
8  3      b
9  4      b
10 5      b
11 1      c
12 2      c
13 3      c
14 4      c
15 5      c
```

Then we can simply perform a join operation on the `df` and your `data`, requesting that we return all the rows from the left hand side (the `x` argument, hence `df`), and include corresponding values for `y` from the right hand side (`data`). Where there is no corresponding right hand side (in `data`, we will get an `NA`.

```
newdf <- merge(df, data, all.x = TRUE)

> newdf
   x factor           y
1  1      a -0.50219235
2  1      b  0.13153117
3  1      c -0.07891709
4  2      a  0.88678481
5  2      b  0.11697127
6  2      c  0.31863009
7  3      a          NA
8  3      b          NA
9  3      c -0.58179068
10 4      a  0.71453271
11 4      b -0.82525943
12 4      c -0.35986213
13 5      a  0.08988614
14 5      b  0.09627446
15 5      c -0.20163395
```

Now we can fit and predict from a loess model by hand, but this is a little tedious - easier options are available via `mgcv:gam()`

```
loessFun <- function(XX, span = 0.85) {
  fit <- loess(y ~ x, data = XX, na.action = na.exclude, span = span)
  predict(fit)
}
```

Now split the data by `factor` and apply the `loessFun()` wrapper

```
fits <- lapply(split(newdf, newdf$factor), loessFun)
newdf <- transform(newdf, fitted = unsplit(fits, factor))

> head(newdf)
  x factor           y      fitted
1 1      a -0.50219235 -0.50219235
2 1      b  0.13153117  0.13153117
3 1      c -0.07891709 -0.07891709
4 2      a  0.88678481  0.88678481
5 2      b  0.11697127  0.11697127
6 2      c  0.31863009  0.31863009
```

We can then plot using the new data frame

```
ggplot(newdf, aes(x = x, y = y, col = factor)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = factor))
```

which gives:

[image]

It looks a bit funky because of the very low resolution of the sample data you provided and because this method that I've used predicts at the observed data only, preserving `NA`s. `geom_smooth()` is actually predicting over the range of `x` for each group separately and as such there are no missing `x`s in the data used to draw the geom layer.

Unless you can explain within what region of `x = 3` we should add a break (an `NA`), this may well be the best that you can do. Alternatively, we could predict over the region from the models and then set anything `2.5 < x < 3.5` back to being `NA`. Add a comment if that is what you wanted and I'll expand my answer with an example of doing that **if** you can indicate how we are to envisage the gaps.